# Doctrine Query Builder Substring

Tags: php, symfony, doctrine-orm, orm, query-builder

Hi i got  following line:

```
$query = $qb->select($qb->expr()->substring("p.website",1,$qb->expr()->length("p.website")-4))
        ->from("AppBundle\Entity\Image" ,"p")
        ->getQuery();
```

and got following Exception:

```
Notice: Object of class Doctrine\ORM\Query\Expr\Func could not be converted to int
```

I understand why this Exception is thrown but how is it possible to get a substring based on the string size with Query Builder?

Comment: What are you want? Can you show `SQL` query?

Answer (score 1):

OK got it...
The expression `$qb->expr()->length("p.website")` is first converted into `LENGTH("p.website")`
So the -4 has to concat as string.

`$qb->expr()->length("p.website") **.'-4'**`

```
$query = $qb->select($qb->expr()->substring("p.website",1,$qb->expr()->length("p.website").'-4))
    ->from("AppBundle\Entity\Image" ,"p")
    ->getQuery();
```

Answer (score 0):

In your `EntityRepository`:

```
public function getAll()
{
    $qb = $this->createQueryBuilder('p');
    $query = $qb
            ->select($qb->expr()->substring("p.website", 1, $qb->expr()->length("p.website").'-4'))
            ->getQuery();
    return $query->getResult();
}
```